# How to drop a single specific mySQL table with one command?

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a single command which can login to mySQL and drop one table inside one database. Using Ubuntu.

My intention is to then schedule this command to delete the table every certain time. But that's not the issue, just the purpose and the reasoning why I'd like it to be one line.

Thanks in advance to any answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run this command in the terminal:

```
mysql -u [username] -p[password] -D [databaseName] -h [hostName] -e 'DROP TABLE [tableName];'
```

Replace all words between brackets with the real database credentials.

Note there is no space between -p and the password. If you leave a space between them like other arguments, the command line will ask you to enter the password.